# mongoose update many don't work with $cond in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem when update the mongodb database using $cond and condition is not work.
This is my code..

```
Book.update({
  _id: {
    $in: keys
  }
},{
$cond: [{
    $gte: ["$item",1]
},{
    $inc:{
      item: -1,
      count: 1
    }
},{
  $set: {
      status: "01"
  },
  $inc:{
    count:1
  }
}
```

]},{
      multi: true
    },function(err, rtn) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('book borrowed',rtn);
      Book.find({
        _id: {
          $in: keys
        }
      }, (err, book) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var y in book) {
          record.books.push({
            book_id: book[y]._id,
            range: book[y].book_range,
            name: book[y].book_name,
            author: book[y].book_author,
            barcode: book[y].barcode
          });
        }
        record.save((err2, rtn) => {
          if (err2) throw err2;
          res.json({
            status: true,
            msg: "Book Borrowing process is succefully complete!!"
          });
        });
      });
    });

Comment: $cond is return one value. So need to add new update query with item:'0' and set status "01"